# Android 9 patch images are only useful for single coloured square shape images?

Tags: android, image, button, nine-patch

Android 9 patch images are only useful for single coloured square shape images. I have button with circle shape, [image: Button image]

how to use 9 patch for this image?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a shape `drawable` in the drawable folder that looks something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
    <gradient android:startColor="#FFFF0000" android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:angle="270"/>
</shape>
```

Modify color code that you want.

(For this example I have saved the drawable as circle.xml and it will have a gradient fill)

Then in your layout you need to define a view and set the shape as the background:

```
<View android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"/>
```

The View defines the size and dimensions of the shape.

Edit - Screenshots of the result of the code

[image: Graphical View]

[image: Code Image]